# Azure B2C Custom policy - how to sign in user to portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am having troubles getting a user signed in to a Power Portal using a custom policy in Azure B2C. I have a custom registration process to take the user through that does the following:

1. Verify E-mail
2. Set password (is a password reset)
3. Set and verify 2FA

I am calling this custom policy by copying the end point URL from Azure B2C, starts like this: https://xxxx.b2clogin.com/xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_FIRSTTIMEREGISTER

At the end of this journey I would like the user to return to the site in a logged in state.

I am sending the claims and the JWT token being corrected looks like it should be good to go.

I have also tried calling the out of the box password reset flow and this also doesn't seem to end up with the user logged into the site.

Hitting the default signupsignin custom policy using the login button (which returns to /signin-aad-b2c_1) get the user signed in fine. Hitting this same custom policy using it's end point (as described above) does not.

Could anyone outline all the things that are needed to ensure the user is logged in at the end of a custom journey? (such as what the policy needs, what the return URL should be, if I am using the correct URL to call the policy).

Many Thanks!

Matt

Sending claims and correct output claims in policy.

Various return URLS (site root, /signin-aad-b2c_1 etc.)

Manipulating the URL given by Azure B2C as the end point.

Have added issuer in site settings.